# Optimal ecosystem simulation class hierarchy?

Tags: object, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, simulation

**Some Background:**

Similar questions have been asked *many* times before, mainly because this usually manifests itself as some Intro-to-OOP homework-esque question about polymorphism. Usually, something a long the lines of "a Dog / Cat class both derive from the Animal but implements a their own speak() method" or something very simple like that.

Unfortunately for those actually looking to make some complex projects around an animal/plant based ecosystem, these simple answers actually make it quite hard to find discussion about a complete class hierarchy around an entire ecosystem.

To some extent, all class hierarchy designs will be specific to how detailed the project gets. For example, I'm not interested in enough detail to make photosynthesis() function for my plant class and model out that kind of fundamental energy relationship from the sun -> plants. But I'd like this class hierarchy boilerplate to be inclusive enough that it wouldn't be *too hard* to make something like that happen if a project wanted to.

So I'm hoping we can come to a consensus about an optimal class hierarchy for an ecosystem that will be general enough to minimize the pain in future refactors/expansions.

---

**Ecosystem Simulation:**

By "ecosystem" simulation, let's take [this](https://youtu.be/r_It_X7v-1E) as an example. There are rabbits that eat the plants, and foxes that eat the rabbits. There are behaviors specific to each class. Reproduction (with genes considered) matter. All LivingEntity's can be "consumed", and all LivingEntity's have some genes that will vary over time.

Here are just some *initial* ideas:

LivingEntity (Abstract)

Animal : LivingEntity (Abstract)

Plant : LivingEntity (Abstract)

Shrub : Plant

Tree : Plant

Rabbit : Animal

Fox : Animal

Probably want something more *expandable though*. Also need to think about **interfaces**. Here are just some ideas that I'm not sure what to do with currenty:

Species?

Tribe? (red rabbits vs. blue rabbits)

Habitats? (burrows, dens)

Hitpoints (ie. a rabbit can "survive" an attack from a fox)?

Just using the concrete examples of rabbits and foxes, but ideally should be expandable to all types of living entities *at any level of the food chain*.

The other concern is that this type of traditional class hierarchy is not scalable for a sufficiently complex ecosystem. Biology is full of edge-case behaviors, but adding behaviors to these classes seems like it could get quite cumbersome. This leads me to believe I need some sort of fundamentally different design pattern.

---

**In Summary:**

In my "big projects" I neglected to optimize the polymorphism before starting, which led to many refactors and a bad experience with OOP. Trying to optimize this *before* I get too deep. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Potentially an answer but there are some details I need to understand before coming to that conclusion:

[This paper](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/%7Eszymansk/theses/S043_Conery.pdf) uses an EventHandler Pattern to try and alleviate some of the problems encountered with adding new behaviors. [image: EventHandler Pattern]

I'm not entirely sure it's the ideal solution, but it looks promising. I lack the full example so I'm still understanding how something like this would completely look.

There does seem to be one significant drawback to this approach:

> limitations in the current design of FOREST are
> that it does not provide any support for modeling interactions
> between organisms

If I understand this correctly, it would be impossible for a rabbit to consume() a plant. Wondering if anyone has some experience around this style of EventHandler pattern to know if this issue can be worked around.